# How to open .bashrc in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with opening the `.bashrc` file in python. I have written the following code:

```
mydata = open ('/home/lpp/.bashrc', 'r')
```

and I get this:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/lpp/lpp2016/Handin3.py
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Python does not open the file `.bashrc`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: It looks like it does (return code 0 and no exception) but you do nothing with it.

Comment: `open('~.bashrc')`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question. I went through the same problem and this is my solution to read the content.

```
with open('.bashrc', 'r') as content:
   fileContent = content.read()
   print(fileContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fp = open(os.path.join((os.path.expanduser('~'), '.bashrc'))
fp.read()
```

it is opening and reading all the content